# How do I convert this query into LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

How do I convert this query into LINQ?

Here `employeeList` is a list of employees(model) and `idList` has a list of ids(int).

```
Update employeeList 
Set employeeList.CaseNumber = '100' 
where employeeList.id in idList
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.  There's no direct conversion from sql to c# (linq or otherwise) without a library of some sort.  Are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes using entity framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a LINQ-Query that will result in the given `UPDATE` query.
The only solution is to iterate through the collection of items and set the `CaseNumber` to 100.

```
foreach(var item in context.employeeList.Where(i => idList.Contains(i.id))
{
    item.CaseNumber = "100";
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

But this will result in `n` queries send to the database.
A better solution is to execute the query directly to the database.

```
context.Database.SqlQuery("UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE");
```

Another possibility would be to use `StoredProcedures` which are then mapped to the `ORM`.

Comment: Won't be able to use a direct Sql query, thanks for the answer.  I have accepted it as answer. The employee list is in memory so it won't be that much of an overhead. I had just put it as an update statement as wanted to convey how i wanted to manipulate the list

Answer (score -1):

If I understood properly, you only need a LINQ alternative to what you wrote.
If that is the case please try the provided code

employeeList.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.id)).ToList().ForEach(i => i.CaseNumber = 100);